# python write list of file prefixes and specific content to another file

Tags: python

I have a list of of file prefixes that was provided as input to a python script. It is in two forms, comma and blank separated. Example (although, they are not always numbered):

```
is0,is1,is2,is3,is4,is5,is6,is7,is8
is0 is1 is2 is3 is4 is5 is6 is7 is8
```

Related code fragment (I manually inserted the newline above):

```
if raw_input_file_list:
    input_file_list = raw_input_file_list.replace(",", " ")
    print(raw_input_file_list, input_file_list)
```

They represent a set of comma separated files, i.e. is0.csv, is1.csv, ...
And the script uses gnuplot to plot the data to a .png file. Then the script creates an HTML file wrapper to display the graph. That part is working fine. Additionally, I am attempting to present a small portion of the data in a table in the HTML file. Example, without borders and such:

```
      number of work packets completed
name  1000  2000  3000  4000
is0   8369 16739 25108 33478
is1  47648 65186 77259 87103
is2  46417 63642 75575 85394
...
```

Where the "1000" column is the corresponding entry from the file. Example:

```
doug@s19:~/freq-scalers/step$ grep ^1000 is?.csv
is0.csv:1000, 8369
is1.csv:1000, 47648
is2.csv:1000, 46417
is3.csv:1000, 46101
is4.csv:1000, 47686
is5.csv:1000, 47018
is6.csv:1000, 38351
is7.csv:1000, 38107
is8.csv:1000, 17354
```

So far I have not been able to even get the file name column, always ending up with one letter per row, let alone extracting the data columns. Example:

```
<table summary="Some Selected Data..." class="dindex">
<TR>
<TD class="dlinks"><P>
i<BR>
s<BR>
0<BR>
,<BR>
i<BR>
s<BR>
1<BR>
,<BR>
```

Code fragments (I have tried a great many methods):

```
    f_handle.write('<table summary="Some Selected Data..." class="dindex">\n')
    f_handle.write('<TR>\n')
    title_list = input_file_list
    f_handle.write('<TD class="dlinks"><P>\n')
    for x in range(len(raw_input_file_list)):
       f_handle.write('{}'.format(raw_input_file_list[x]))
       f_handle.write('<BR>\n')
    f_handle.write('</P></TD>\n')
    f_handle.write('<TD class="dlinks"><P>\n')
    for f in input_file_list:
       f_handle.write('{}\n'.format(f))
    f_handle.write('</P></TD>\n')
```

Where f_handle is:

```
f_handle = open('index.html', 'w')
```

Obviously python is not may area of knowledge. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `raw_input_file_list` is a `string`, `raw_input_file_list[x]` is the `x`th character of that `string`.

What you might want to do is to use the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html) method to split the `string` by commas into a `list`, and iterate through that `list`:

```py
foo_list = raw_input_file_list.split(",")
for file_name in foo_list:
    # file name would be is0 then is1 etc.
    f_handle.write(file_name)
    f_handle.write('<BR>\n')
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: That works great, thank you. Can you help at all with how to open the files and extract the data for the other columns of the table?

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to check out the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to extract data from the csv files. By the way, if my answer has solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks!